# Prevent overfitting in Predict function

Tags: neural-networks, version-12

I know that you can prevent overtraining automatically in a network if you use `NetTrain` with `NetChain` in Mathematica version 12, but is there a way to prevent overtraining when using the Predict function to train a network? Or is overfitting prevention already built into the function itself? I can't seem to find any leads in the documentation page. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There are some bits in the docs for `Predict` about L2Regularization and the ValidationSet option. It doesn't explicitly mention overfitting, but I think it does attempt to prevent it using regularization. Divide your data into something like 70-30 training to validation and try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Props to @flinty for this answer.

I played around with the `Predict` function with the `ValidationSet` option, and used 1500 data points for training with 500 for validation.

Displaying the L2Regularization value afterwards yielded a value of 0. Thus meaning that overfitting prevention should already be included in the Predict function, and it automatically prevents overfitting all by itself.